# PHP script to accept user parameters

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I'm looking for a **tutorial/link to get started with user parameters within URLs**.
I've looked online but can't seem to find anything that starts from scratch (most of them are for rewriting and imply that the URLs are already dynamic).

Right now, all my user profiles' URLs are localhost/profile.php and i'd like them to be localhost/profile.php?id=foo.

Once this is done, i'll use the rewrite module to get more friendly URLs.

Thanks !

ps: I am not using any framework.

Comment: Your question is way too broad for Stackoverflow. Asking for tutorial links is normally considered off-topic even. I wonde a bit why you think it's appropriate to ask actually. And as you're looking for pointers: *php variables from external sources* I think this is in the manual.

Comment: @hakre i asked because, correct me if I'm wrong, "Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers."

Comment: So I hope that tagline made you curious and you continued to read then? Like http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The php superglobals $_GET and $_POST are used to access parameters from get and post requests respectively, In your case a get request...

```
<?php

$value_of_id = $_GET['id'];
echo $value_of_id; //foo

?>
```

once you get the value of the id you can check it against a database and then proceed with your profle authentication, by showing their data from the db.